# Error occurred when running python3 darknet_video.py

Tags: python, opencv, yolo, darknet

I've git-cloned the website ( https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) to get darknet yolo on my Jetson NANO. But when I'm trying to run darknet_video.py by

```
python3 darknet_video.py
```

it shows the error code bellow

```
[ERROR:0] global /tmp/pip-build-im21wrqj/opencv-python/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (142) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:
```

`OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-build-im21wrqj/opencv-python/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:293: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_filename.empty() in function 'open'

While I'm having opencv 4.4.0

Has anyone here met this problem before or can help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

How have you installed OpenCV?

For a simple fix, you can try this `sudo apt install libopencv-dev python3-opencv`

Also make sure you have cmake,

`sudo apt install cmake`

This should install opencv 3.2 and cmake 3.10 in your system. Then try running darknet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but yes, I've just made sure again that I have all the options that you have mentioned above. But it's still not working.